# I tagged in git-svn, and now my master always commits to the svn tag!

Tags: git, git-svn

I've got a basic git-svn setup:

```
   [core]
           repositoryformatversion = 0
           filemode = false
           bare = false
           logallrefupdates = true
           symlinks = false
           ignorecase = true
           hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
           autocrlf = true
   [svn-remote "svn"]
           url = https://svnserver:8443/svn/Project
           fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
           branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/*
           tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

I created a tag off the trunk (master in git) by issuing the following:

```
git svn tag -m "3.6.1" 3.6.1
```

This created a new tag in svn at /tags/3.6.1.  In addition, I saw a new /remotes/tags/3.6.1 listed in my remote branches.

At some point, I'd checkout out a local branch from the 3.6.1 remote and made some changes.  Then I merged them into the master (I think this was a big mistake).  So my master seems to think it has some history from the 3.6.1 tag.

Now every time I commit something to my master then dcommit, they're going to the 3.6.1 tag!

```
jakes@mymachine /cygdrive/d/Projects/Project (master)
$ git svn dcommit
Committing to https://svnserver:8443/svn/Project/tags/3.6.1 ...
    M       fileThatChanged.js
Committed r6027
```

Is there an easy way I can set things straight again?

Comment: "checkout out a local branch from the 3.6.1 remote" -- why? Don't you actually want to checkout a local branch from `trunk`?

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I've used git svn, but try a command like this:

```
git branch --set-upstream svn/trunk
```

or

```
git branch --set-upstream refs/remotes/trunk
```

If that doesn't work can you post the `[branch "master"]` section of your git config as well?

Comment: -1 `git branch --set-upstream` is pointless, since git-svn does not use the normal git upstream information - it uses its own mechanism.

Comment: Are you certain, afaik --set-upstream simply sets the fetch value in the configuration, which is still used by git svn.

Comment: No, it does not. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975754/which-remote-branches-are-my-local-git-svn-branches-bound-to/20976651 for details.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but figured I'd post anyway. I didn't have luck using --set-upstream (or the more recent --set-upstream-to). If you don't have changes in your local branch, you can do something like

```
git checkout remotes/trunk
git checkout -B master
```

That will recreate your local master from remotes/trunk. The same workflow could be applied to remote branches that you want to track locally.

To prevent the issue happening that you referred to, I've found the best way to merge is using

```
git merge --no-ff local/feature_branch
```